# NextJS gallery layout broke on mobile, but not on my desktop chrome in mobile mode

Tags: reactjs, next.js, responsive-design, jquery-isotope

Using NextJS
my gallery broke on real mobile, but not when I try on my computer with the inspector, since I cant reproduce the bug I dont know how to manage this issue,
Maybe its initIsotope ? but im not sure, any help will be appreciate

Here a sample of the component for my gallery

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import initIsotope from "../../common/initIsotope";

const Portfolio = ({ grid, filterPosition }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
  initIsotope();
}, 1000);
}, []);
return (
<section className="portfolio section-padding pb-70">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row justify-content-center">
      <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10">
        <div className="sec-head text-center">
          <h6 className="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            LATEST WORK
          </h6>
          <h3 className="wow color-font">
            Portfolio Showcase
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className={`${grid === 3 ? "container-fluid" : "container"}`}>
    <div className="row">
      <div
        className={`filtering ${
          filterPosition === "center"
            ? "text-center"
            : filterPosition === "left"
            ? "text-left"
            : "text-right"
        } col-12`}
      >
        <div className="filter">
          <span data-filter="*" className="active">
            All
          </span>
          <span data-filter=".mobile">Mobile App</span>
          <span data-filter=".web">Website</span>
          <span data-filter=".webapp">Web App</span>
          <span data-filter=".solana">Solana</span>
          <span data-filter=".btc">Bitcoin</span>
          <span data-filter=".polygon">Polygon</span>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="gallery full-width">
        <div
          className={`${
            grid === 3
              ? "col-lg-4 col-md-6"
              : grid === 2
              ? "col-md-6 lg-mr"
              : "col-12"
          } items solana web wow fadeInUp`}
          data-wow-delay=".4s"
        >
          <div className="item-img">
           {/* <Link href={`/project-details2/project-details2-dark`}>*/}
              <a className="imago wow">
                <img src="/img/portfolio/portfolio/1/1.jpg" alt="Ninja Wallet Website" />
                <div className="item-img-overlay"></div>
              </a>
           {/* </Link>*/}
          </div>
          <div className="cont">
            <h6>Ninja Wallet Website</h6>
            <span>
              <Link href="#">NextJS</Link>, <Link href="#">Design</Link>, <Link href="#">Token</Link>, <Link href="#">STAKING</Link>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div
          className={`${
            grid === 3
              ? "col-lg-4 col-md-6"
              : grid === 2
              ? "col-md-6"
              : "col-12"
          } items webapp solana wow fadeInUp`}
          data-wow-delay=".4s"
        >
          <div className="item-img">
           {/* <Link href={`/project-details2/project-details2-dark`}>*/}
              <a className="imago wow">
                <img src="/img/portfolio/portfolio/1/2.jpg" alt="Ninja Wallet Chrome Extension" />
                <div className="item-img-overlay"></div>
              </a>
           {/* </Link>*/}
          </div>
          <div className="cont">
            <h6>Ninja Wallet Chrome Extension</h6>
            <span>
              <a href="#0">NextJS</a>, <a href="#0">Solana</a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

It looks great on desktop mobile with the inspector:

[image]

but buggy on real phone like :

[image]